# Combine data and push to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```js
let friends = [{ Friend: 'Example', id: '123' },
{ Friend: 'Example', id: '123' },
{ Friend: 'Example', id: '123' }]

let name = John;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    friends: [{ Friend: String, id: String}],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

How can I insert the name at 'name' and the array at 'friends' data? Can I create an empty database entry and then push it in or should I create a new entry with both values?

Comment: What is your find condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
const addToFriends = async () => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ name: user name });
        user.name = name;
        user.friends.friend = name;
        await user.save();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
};
```

Comment: const user = await User.findOne({ name: user.name }) ?

Comment: @benjosua No, there go the name of the user where you want to add the `let name` variable